# Criando elementos html em looping javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loop

Sou bem novo com javascript e quando se trata de criar loopings eu me perco totalmente, o código abaixo é para criar os elementos a cada clique e numerar o `id` e o texto, mas estou tendo dificuldades quanto a isso, eu consegui, resolver com um input e adicionando a quantidade, porém não é esse o resultado que preciso, como devo proceder? Se possível explique as alterações, Obrigado.

```js
document.getElementById("add1").onclick = function clone(){
 var qt = 1;
 var container = document.getElementById("saida1");
 while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
  container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
 }
 for (i=0;i<qt;i++){

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  var div2 = document.createElement("div");
  var div3 = document.createElement("div");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  div1.className = "linha";
  div2.className = "coluna1";
  div3.className = "coluna2";
  label.htmlFor = (i+1)
  label.textContent = "Texto " + (i+1) + ": ";
  input.className = (i+1);
  input.name = "inp";
  input.type = "text";
  container.appendChild(div1);
  div1.appendChild(div2);
  div2.appendChild(label);
  div1.appendChild(div3);
  div3.appendChild(input);
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="saida1"></div>
<button id="add1">ADD</button>
```

Comment: primeiro, se a variável "qt" é sempre igual a 1, esse comando `for (i=0;i<qt;i++){` é sem propósito, irá fazer tudo sempre uma vez, ele é desnecessário. Segundo, essa linha remove os itens que já tem na div "container": `container.removeChild(container.lastChild);` então só irá aparecer 1 elemento sempre. Por fim, você teria de contar quantos elementos tem na div "container" para poder numerar

Comment: eu esqueci de remover `...container.removeChild(container.lastChild);...` de quando fiz o código usando input para pegar os valores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem melhorias que podem ser feitas no seu código, mas para responder suas dúvidas quanto ao *loop* e como fazer o contador, vou manter o código como está e adicionar comentários para explicar:

```js
document.getElementById("add1").onclick = function clone() {
    // removi o qt que não será mais usado e estava sem função como explicarei abaixo
    var container = document.getElementById("saida1");
    // removi o while, que só estava excluindo os elementos, por isso também aparecia somente um
    
    // conta quantos elementos com classe linha existem
    // isso vai servir para montar o label e o id dos novos elementos
    var i = document.querySelectorAll(".linha").length;

   // removi o for porque, como qt sempre era igual a 1, nunca contava nada diferente e só executava uma vez
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    var div3 = document.createElement("div");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    div1.className = "linha";
    div2.className = "coluna1";
    div3.className = "coluna2";
    label.htmlFor = (i + 1)
    label.textContent = "Texto " + (i + 1) + ": ";
    input.className = (i + 1);
    input.name = "inp";
    input.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(div2);
    div2.appendChild(label);
    div1.appendChild(div3);
    div3.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="saida1"></div>
<button id="add1">ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

A cada clique no botão "ADD" você quer adicionar um novo input, certo?

Pq você remove todos os campos antes de adicionar +1?

```
while (container.hasChildNodes()) {

    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);

}
```

Para resolver o problema, você precisa:

1. Contar quantos elementos já estão inseridos no container "saida1".
2. Armazenar a quantidade em alguma variável acrescentada de +1.
3. Inserir o novo input

Você não precisa de um loop, pode fazer:

```js
document.getElementById("add1").onclick = function clone() {

    //Local onde será inserido o input
 var container = document.getElementById("saida1");

    //Conta total de elementos e soma +1 para o que irá ser adicionado
    var total = container.childElementCount+1

    var input = document.createElement("input");
 var div1 = document.createElement("div");
 var div2 = document.createElement("div");
 var div3 = document.createElement("div");
 var label = document.createElement("label");

 div1.className = "linha";
 div2.className = "coluna1";
 div3.className = "coluna2";

    //diferencie os labels para que sejam unicos
 label.htmlFor = 'input_' + total
    //insira o titulo com o novo total
 label.textContent = "Texto " + total + ": ";
 input.className = total;
 input.name = "inp";
 input.type = "text";
    //Inclui um ID para cada input, de acordo com o label
    input.id = 'input_' + total;
 container.appendChild(div1);
 div1.appendChild(div2);
 div2.appendChild(label);
 div1.appendChild(div3);
 div3.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div id="saida1"></div>
<button id="add1">ADD</button>
```

Comment: eu esqueci de remover `...container.removeChild(container.lastChild);...` de quando fiz o código usando input para pegar os valores

Answer (score 1):

As outras respostas que tem já lhe explicam o problema e o que fez errado, mas quero mostrar outra solução ao mesmo problema.

Se precisa de adicionar muito html dinamicamente pode utilizar [*templates*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) que lhe facilitam o processo, pois permitem-lhe manter o html que quer criar como html e criar os novos elementos clonando o que já está no html.

Exemplo:

```js
let cont = 1;
document.getElementById("add1").onclick = function clone() {
  let container = document.getElementById("saida1");  
  let tempLinha = document.querySelector('#templateLinha'); //obter o template
  let clone = document.importNode(tempLinha.content, true); //clonar
  
  //alterar o que interessa no template clonado
  const label = clone.querySelector("label");
  label.htmlFor = cont;
  label.textContent = "Texto " + (cont) + ": ";
  clone.querySelector("input").className = cont;
  
  container.appendChild(clone);
  cont++;
}
```

```html
<div id="saida1"></div>
<button id="add1">ADD</button>

<!-- aqui está o template do html que cada nova linha leva -->
<template id="templateLinha">
  <div class="linha">
    <div class="coluna1">
        <label for="1">Texto 1: </label>
    </div>
    <div class="coluna2">
      <input class="1" name="inp" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Repare que no html acrescentei uma nova tag `<template>` com a estrutura que você adiciona em cada linha. Isto tem também a vantagem de tornar mais claro o html que constitui cada uma. Depois sobre o `clone` que foi criado, obtive os elementos que pretendia com `querySelector` e troquei apenas as coisas que precisavam de ficar diferentes.

Deixo no entanto aqui o aviso que está funcionalidade não é suportada no antigo Internet Explorer.

Comment: Muito interessante não conhecia, vou testar obrigado.